# Saving/exporting raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I am trying to save edits to a raster file in QGIS, but;

1. When you edit a raster file and select "Save As"; no output file is generated.
2. My version is in Spanish; however "Save as raster layer" is displayed. Just as "Output"

How do I properly save/export a raster in QGIS?

Comment: "EDIT" a `raster` file? You sure you don't mean a vector layer?

Comment: I have the same problem on QGIS 2.4, when saving a raster (saveas) no file is generated. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Welcome to gis.se. Please edit your thread title to a meaningful question which provides enough details for future readers who might come here with a similar problem looking for solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what this is about.

First, it is not really an EDIT of the raster that is performed; it is probably just a change in the rendering (changing visualisation style in the raster properties).

For example moving from a "single-band grey" towards a "single-band pseudocolor" and thus obtaining a color visualisation. After doing so, you would like to SAVE your color result AS a new image where pixels have new values reflecting the pseudocolors you previously obtained. So at this point, if you right-click in your image in the layers panel, you will find a "save as" option displayed, suggesting that you could probably obtain your new image.

The problem (at least in QGIS 2.4) is that when you proceed to save your new image, no file is recorded... and I think this is the question about: why this "save as" option does not give any result?.

Answer (score 1):

First to save/export a raster layer, you can use Raster/Conversion/Translate (covert format). You can define the file format,  the CRS and null values, among other things. Selecting the raster layer and chosing save as is not the procedure (I think you may have a little of ArcMap in mind...)

Nevertheles I have to agree with Curlew, are you sure that you edited a raster file? If so can you tell us exactly what you did?

Comment: Thank you, Gerardo. 

When you select a raster layer and chosing "save as", QGIS supports two output modes: 

1) raw data 
2) rendered image. 

In converting format, does not give me the option to "rendered image" (in QGIS 2.2, it worked).