# Unable to adjust raster symbology in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, symbology, display

I am bringing in raster (tif) data (ocean pH) into ArcGIS (exported from QGIS). 
I expected it to come in in a way that I could adjust the colours.  However, it is coming in as RGB colour bands (three bands) and I am unable to query the pH values. Is there a different way to bring in the data so I would be able to adjust the colours and query the values?

[image]

Comment: How did you export it from Q (do you mean QGIS?)? Did you create the data or did you download it?

Comment: A coworker exported it from QGIS.  The original data is NetCDF data - with many time bands and in lat/long coordinates.  
This can be a challenge to work with in Arc - hence bringing it into QGIS first.

Comment: Tell him to export data (raster) not a picture on display

Comment: @FelixIP is absolutely correct, your co-worker has exported the display and not the data. They need to follow the answers in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107300/how-do-i-properly-save-export-a-raster-in-qgis to export the data properly.

Comment: Further, ArcGIS has tools devoted to working with NetCDF files. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/netcdf/reading-netcdf-data-using-geoprocessing-tools.htm

Comment: Thanks.  I have used these tools for other NetCDF data sets but they don't work well if the data is in lat/long (uneven spatial grid).

Answer (score 1):

You have received an image representing your raster data.  You need the actual raster data.  It sounds like there are several bands on the source raster data.  You'll need to ask for an export of the ocean ph band, if that is the info you want.

You will need to go back to the source and ask for an export of the raster data, not just an image export from QGIS.

You will then be able to query the raster data to find the values you are looking for and you will be able to symbolize based on the raster values.

Comment: Thanks.  I will check this out.  The bands of data are different time slices of the ocean pH data.